# Xslt transform in .net without escaping <

Tags: xml, character-encoding, xslt

Here is my code:

```
XElement transformed = new XElement("stuff");
using (XmlWriter writer = transformed.CreateWriter())
{
  _xslt.Transform(section.CreateReader(), writer);
}
```

where `_xslt` is a `XslCompiledTransform` and `section` is an `XElement`.
After the transform, the writer has content where the < has changed to `&lt;`. This is not an issue with the xsl because if I use an XmlWriter that saves to a file, I do NOT see this escaping. The xsl has a few `<xsl:value-of ... disable-output-escaping="yes">` transforms and those are the ones causing an issue. Again, if I write the transform to a file, there is not a problem. Thought I might need to change some of the settings for the writer, but `XElement.CreateWriter` does not have a constructor that takes an `XmlWriterSettings`.

Is there a way to do this without transforming to a string or stringbuilder and then reparsing back into XElement?

**New Info**

Instead of the XmlWriter, I changed my code to:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter())
{
  _xslt.Transform(section.CreateReader(), null, writer);
}
```

The StreamWriter has non-escaped characters like I want, now, how do I get that loaded back into my XElement?

**Request for more info**

Here's the xsl that works fine with a StreamWriter, but not with an XmlWriter:

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction(mark_start')">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;addtext></xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('mark_end')">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/addtext></xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

And no, I have no control over the xml so I am stuck with the processing instructions as given. In summary, the DOE works with StreamWriter but not XmlWriter.

**Request for Sample XML**

Here is what the xml looks like that I'm processing:

```
<text>
    this is some text
    <?mark_start>
    and some new text
    <?mark_end>
    and the rest of the text
</text>
```

Comment: Please show part of the XML you're transforming, and the transformed XML.

Comment: I added more info above.

Comment: @Wave: please post the bad resulting XML

Comment: @JS: As I mentioned in my question, I am getting &lt; instead of < as the output. This does not happen if I use a StreamWriter like I've shown in my answer below.

Comment: @Wave: and why not post the XML so we can see what's going on? Why make us guess?

Comment: @JS: Because the issue isn't the xml, it's the encoding of XmlWriter versus StreamWriter. I have added an example above.

Comment: @Wavel: Really? Check my answer for a "standar" XSLT way of doing this transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until someone shows me something better:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        _xslt.Transform(section.CreateReader(), null, writer);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        transformed = XElement.Load(stream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your basic problem is that you are abusing the XSLT language by trying to write tags rather than writing nodes. Outputting a start tag from one template and the corresponding end tag from another is not the way XSLT is designed to be used. It looks as if you are processing some kind of "overlap markup" in the source document; doing this properly is a complex subject with an extensive literature. Resorting to writing tags using disable-output-escaping is tempting, but you need to understand (as your experiments demonstrate) that it will only work when the XSLT processor is writing serialized lexical XML as its output, and you will then need to re-parse that XML to make it available for the next stage of processing.

Comment: I would agree that I'm abusing xslt :) However, I'm being abused with the xml I've been given as input!! You are correct in that I'm trying to start a node with one PI and end it with another in an attempt to take the given xml and turn it into something a lot better structured. The answer I posted above does at least get the job done, but I'd very much apreciate a pointer for learning about "overlap markup".

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('mark_start')">
        <addtext>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
        </addtext>
        <xsl:apply-templates
             select="following-sibling::processing-instruction('mark_end')
                        /following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('mark_end')"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<text>
    this is some text
    <addtext>
    and some new text
    </addtext>
    and the rest of the text
</text>
```

**Note**: Fine grained traversal.

Comment: I stand humbly corrected. I guess i have to compare the complexity of your solution with that of the memorystream/streamwriter solution I came up with. Thank you for your answer.